# How is formula for mean ionic activity derived from its constituent activities?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, stoichiometry

I spent hours in order to understand the following - but without success:

At many places the mean ionic activity coefficient  for the reaction

$$\ldots  \rightarrow \nu_A A^{z_A+} + \nu_B B^{z_B-}$$
is defined as

$$\gamma_{\pm} = \left(\gamma_A^{\nu_A}\gamma_B^{\nu_B}\right)^\frac{1}{\nu_A+\nu_B}$$

The single activity coefficients for A and B are, using Debye-Hückel's law and the ion strength I:

$$\log \gamma_A = -A \cdot z_A^2 \cdot \sqrt I$$
$$\log \gamma_B = -A \cdot z_B^2 \cdot \sqrt I$$

This means

$$\gamma_A = 10^{-A \cdot z_A^2 \cdot \sqrt I}$$
$$\gamma_B = 10^{-A \cdot z_B^2 \cdot \sqrt I}$$

and

$$\gamma_A^{\nu_A} = 10^{-A \cdot z_A^2 \cdot \sqrt I \cdot \nu_A}$$
$$\gamma_B^{\nu_B} = 10^{-A \cdot z_B^2 \cdot \sqrt I \cdot \nu_B}$$

Finally, this gives

$$\gamma^{\pm} = \left(10^{-A \cdot z_A^2 \cdot \sqrt I \cdot \nu_A} \cdot 10^{-A \cdot z_B^2 \cdot \sqrt I \cdot \nu_B}\right)^\frac{1}{\nu_A+\nu_B}$$

$$\gamma^{\pm} = 10^{-\frac{A \sqrt I \cdot (z_A^2 \nu_A+z_B^2 \nu_B)}{\nu_A+\nu_B}}$$

$$\log \gamma^{\pm} = -\frac{A \sqrt I \cdot (z_A^2 \nu_A+z_B^2 \nu_B)}{\nu_A+\nu_B}$$

But I read always

$$\log \gamma^{\pm} = -A \cdot |z_A \cdot z_B| \cdot \sqrt I$$

So what's going on here?

EDIT:

According to the hint below (see comment)

For **charge balance** I have to set

$$z_A=\nu_B$$
$$z_B=\nu_A$$

and so I get for the factor on the right

$$\frac{z_A^2 \nu_A+z_B^2 \nu_B}{\nu_A+\nu_B} = \frac{z_A^2 z_A+z_B^2 z_A}{z_A+z_B}= z_A z_B$$

So it is solved.

Comment: Don’t you have charge neutrality on the right hand side of your first expression? Seems like that provides the missing piece.

Comment: @Ed V: You mean what I added to my question at the end (its easier to write there): how embarrassing it is to me - I've fiddled for hours and then it's so easy...

Comment: No biggie: glad to have helped a bit!

Comment: What a shame...sometimes I feel like an idiot afterwards ;-)

Comment: Happens to us all!